# Scala how to recover exception in a for future

Tags: scala, exception, concurrent.futures

Here is my question!
When I use several future tasks in a for expression, I'm confused with the result of exception recover.

```
object ForTest {    
  def ft1(n: Int): Future[Int] = Future(n*2)
  def ft2(n: Int): Future[Int] = Future(60/n)
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val n = 0
    val res =
      for {
        a1 <- ft1(n)
        a2 <- ft2(n)
      } yield (a1,a2)    
    res.map{ x =>
      println(s"x=$x")
    }.recover{
      case t: Throwable =>
        println(s"exception ${t.getStackTrace}")
    }    
  }
}
```

Above is my code. Sometimes it print out the exception, sometimes not, I'm totally confused. Can anyone help me?

Comment: your program will exit when the main method returns, which may happen before the futures have finished executing since they execute threads of the ExecutionContext and not the main thread.

Comment: Simply add `Await.result(res,Duration.Inf)` at the end of the main method

Comment: Oh my god! Many thanks!